# How to - Custom WebPart acting as a consumer to SharePoint List Filter WebPart

Tags: 2010

I am trying to create a custom webpart which will act as a consumer webpart to the SharePoint List Filter WebPart. I have not been able to make this code work, the send filter values to option is disabled on the List filter web part. any ideas?

```
namespace PageViewerWithConnections.CustomPageViewer
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class CustomPageViewer : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {
        IFilterValues _filterVals;

        [ConnectionConsumer("Market")]
        public void ConsumeFilter(IFilterValues filterValues)
        {
            _filterVals = filterValues;
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not added any parameters that you support to filterValues. See the example in [Walkthrough: Writing a Simple Filter Consumer Web Part Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms490609%28v=office.12%29.aspx) specifically step 1 and SetConnectionInterface

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I am now getting the dreaded "Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

Show Error Details 
" error. I asked another question here http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/10034/getting-error-unhandled-exception-was-thrown-by-the-sandboxed-code-wrapper

Comment: You can't do web part connections in the sandbox IIRC.